# What is the best generalization for the linear sequence operator *first difference* for integer sequences?

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, linear-transformations

By best I mean most useful (seems to have the most applications).

Take an integer sequence $a(n) \in \Bbb{Z}, n \geq 1$.  Form the first difference operator $T(a)(n) = a(n) - a(n-1), n \geq 2;  \ T(a)(1) = a(1)$.  It has the property that it is linear in the linear space of integer sequences.  And it has an inverse $S(a)(n) = \sum_{k =1}^{n} a(n)$ which is also clearly linear.

But I don't see how a matrix could be involved here.  It would be nice to have some sort of matrix-described generalization of this.

Also, what does this space of invertible linear operators look like?  Does it have a basis?

Comment: Do you know convolution and the Fourier series ? $h \ast a(n) = \sum_{m=-\infty}^\infty h(m) a(n-m)$. Convolution operators become multiplication in the Fourier domain. If say $h \in l^2$, convolution by $h\ne 0$ is inversible on $l^2$ one-sided sequences. And the convolution inverse is bounded (in the $l^2$ sense) iff $|\hat{h}(\xi)| \ge \epsilon > 0$ with $\hat{h}$ the Fourier series of $h$.

Comment: @reuns yeah, I've heard of that, what structure does the vector space + convolution form?

Comment: For finite sequences it is called a convolution algebra. For infinite sequences we need a norm and it is a Banach algebra. The convolutive inverse is a non-trivial problem which leads to the convergence theorems for Fourier series and things like the spectral theorem for unbounded operators.

Comment: What to say then. There is the Shannon sampling theorem : if $f(t), t \in \mathbb{R}$ satisfies some smoothness conditions and $a(n) = f(n)$ then you can reconstruct $f$ from $a(n)$ : $f(t) = \sum_n a(n) \frac{\sin(\pi (t-n))}{\pi(t-n)}$. By differentiating and sampling this last series you get that $f'(t) = \sum_n b(n) \frac{\sin(\pi (t-n))}{\pi(t-n)}$ where $b(m) = \sum_n a(n) \frac{d}{dt}\frac{\sin(\pi (t-n))}{\pi(t-n)}|_{t=m}$ the operator $a \mapsto b$ being called an ideal derivative filter. Approximating it in practice is a big deal in signal processing and electrical engineering.